# regex javascript/jquery with url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this code:

```
if(/^\/[^/]+\/[^/]+\/collections/.test(location.pathname)) { alert("ok")};
```

This match with:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/hyperrjas/collections
```

The problem is that also match with:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/hyperrjas/collections/thing1
http://localhost:3000/es/hyperrjas/collections/thing2
http://localhost:3000/es/hyperrjas/collections/thing3
.
.
.
```

I need only match with the first type url:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/hyperrjas/collections
http://localhost:3000/es/michael-25/collections
http://localhost:3000/es/other_username/collections
```

**I don't want match the urls with thing1, thing2, thing3....etc**

**How can I fix this regex javascript?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add on the delimiter `$` to the end of the regular expression

---

Your **new** expression would look like this:

```
/^\/[^/]+\/[^/]+\/collections$/
```

Comment: THank you can you write how does works with this regexp, `if(/^\/[^/]+\/[^/]+\/collections/.test(location.pathname)) { alert("ok")};`